# The difference between __attribute__((unused)) and __attribute((unused)) in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

`__attribute__((unused))` and `__attribute((unused))` can mark variables as unused to avoid unused warning.

What is the difference between them？

Comment: @unwind Can you answer this question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can it? Only the first syntax is documented!

Comment: @JanHudec Yes, it can.

Comment: @JanHudec you mean __attribute((unused)) is non-existent?

Comment: There is a [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) you can find to clarify these things. Yes, the difference is that `__attribute` is just a mis-spelling of the correct `__attribute__`.

Comment: __attribute((unused)) is also take effect in build. It should not be spelling mistake.

Comment: @Xiaoyao, it might be #define'd somewhere to the correct form. But the manual does not define it, so whatever it does, it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GCC repository, in the file [c-common.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/b5d1989793d030cedaa0afee81fc5e7bb4021dc9/gcc/c-family/c-common.c), the array `c_common_reswords` of the type `struct c_common_resword` is defined.

In the array, you will find the following elements:

```
 { "__attribute",   RID_ATTRIBUTE,  0 },
 { "__attribute__", RID_ATTRIBUTE,  0 },
```

And `RID_ATTRIBUTE` is defined in [c-common.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/b5d1989793d030cedaa0afee81fc5e7bb4021dc9/gcc/c-family/c-common.h) in the `enum rid` in the `/* C extensions */` section.

So `__attribute` and `__attribute__` are the same.